macOS change Native TextReplacment list from terminal
Good afternoon everyone, recently I had here a question in which I was helped to solve my question about adding a new key-value pair to text replacement on macOS.
Now I've found a way to do it with just one command using the terminal
Here she is
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems -array-add '{on=1;replace="uuuuuu";with="yyyyy";}'

Then I enter the following command to check if a new pair has been added to the general array
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems

Here we get a list of all pairs, and here we see that our pair has been successfully added
},
    {
    on = 1;
    replace = uuuuuu;
    with = yyyyy;
}
)

And in the end, I ask for the following command to apply the changes
 killall -u $(whoami) cfprefsd 

But after overloading the system when entering the command
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems

The pair I added earlier is no longer there
Tell me, is it possible to add new pairs to replace the text in this way? If so, how to apply the list changes??
I will be grateful for any help!

Interesting, but IMHO, such questions are meant to be posted to [apple.se], an apple specific part of StackExchange. Good luck.

@shellter Thank you very much! I published my question there)

People get mad if you duplicate postings, it's called cross-posting, it it often gets negative votes when the link to the cross-post is added as a comment. Best to delete this version of your question. If you get not results there, then repost here and specify the history of your attempts to get a solution. Good luck.
